# Grant root privileges only for one directory

Tags: linux, centos

What is the best way to grant sudo privileges to a user only for the `/opt/myapp` directory as if the user were root in CentOS?

The idea is to allow developers to do whatever they want only on the `/opt/myapp` directory but to avoid for example that they remove some important directory or shutdown the server.

Comment: If you merely want a user to have full read/write/execute permission on `/opt/myapp`, then set the permissions that way.  If you want something else, you will need to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to give each of them (or the whole bunch) a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you could use chroot environment

http://www.serverschool.com/dedicated-servers/how-to-build-a-chroot-environment-in-centos/

Comment: Please don't just provide links for your answers. What happens when that page is moved/deleted?

Answer (score -1):

There are two really simple ways of doing this:

1) If you want everyone to see it you can change the permissions (chmod 421 /opt/myapp)
where 4 is read 2 is write and 1 is execute

2) If you want only one person to view it you can change the owner of the file (chown newOner /opt/myapp)

Both of these will most likely require root

Answer (score -1):

First, define (within /etc/sudoers) a Cmnd_Alias for the commands you want the user to be able to run:
    Cmnd_Alias MYAPPS = /opt/myapp/some_executable, /opt/myapp/another_one
Then create a user rule that allows them to run them
    some_user ALL = MYAPPS